# React Native - Setting state in fetch promise

Tags: react-native, promise, fetch, use-state

I have a fetch operation to receive coordinates into map markers. It works but it gives this error

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
at Screens/MapPage.js:71:45 in fetch.then.then$argument_0
```

The error line is in setLocations(result.data). The application works fine but I realized this error only occurs when I switch screens without waiting fetch completed. If I go back to home page without waiting setLocations is fetched.   Is there better way to set the state into fetch result? I don't understand Where I am doing wrong?

```
        fetch(baseUrl + "api/Product/GetAllProductLocalization", requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((result) =>  {setLocations(result.data);} )
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error most likely because some update before `setLocations(result.data)` is unmounted the component you called the `fetch` in.

Meaning, `setLocations(result.data)` is trying to update the state of a component that has been unmounted at which point it throws a warning.

As a friendly recommendation, you should probably check out [react-query](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query) library, as well as [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) instead of fetch.

You can check the docs on their site

https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-cancellation#using-fetch

Comment: The application works fine but I realized this error only occurs when I switch screens without waiting fetch completed. If I go back to home page without waiting setLocations is fetched. The error is shown in the terminal.